# Numbers in separate divs have default number if null

Tags: php

I have a number i'm taking out of database, basically votes.

So numbers are going to be separate.

```
For example [ ] = A div styled box.

And $foo = 100

it will display like this:

[ 1 ] [ 0 ] [ 0 ].

        <?php
        for($i=0; $i<strlen($counter); $i++) {
            echo "<div class='votebg'>$counter[$i]</div>";
        }
        ?>
```

But I made this work automatically, just by taking the INT from the database.

Now my int is empty, so I put up a checker to check if its empty, if it is, it will make it 0.

```
if (empty($rcvotes)) {
$rcvotes = 0;
}
```

Now my page only displays a zero

```
[ 0 ]
```

How do I make it so it automatically fills the missing number with a zero if not exists?

For example, we have 7 votes.

The number will display like this:

```
[ 0 ] [ 0 ] [ 7 ]
```

We have 88 votes, the number will display like this:

```
[ 0 ] [ 8 ] [ 8 ]
```

What is exactly the problem?

Thanks!

```
mysql_query('SELECT FROM * `vote_count`');
$rcvotes = $row['vote_number'];
if (empty($rcvotes)) {
$rcvotes = 0;
}

$counter = strval($rcvotes);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [string padding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php):

```
$counter = str_pad($rcvotes, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```